# Mongo C# Driver with ObjectId

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm having troubles with converting the `Guid` into `BinData`. I know that you can just map the property with `BsonIdAttribute`, but in my case I actually need to write the query in JSON format with filter clause for my `Guid` identifier.

Like:

```
mongoClient.UpdateMany(
    new JsonFilterDefinition<UserUnreadCounter>($"{{ \"Counters.EntityId\": {{ $eq: '{myGuid.ConvertToBinData()}' }} }}"),
    new JsonUpdateDefinition<UserUnreadCounter>("{ $inc: { \"Counters.$.Count\": 1 } }"));
```

How can I convert it? Does it just crop the first 24 symbols of hex representation of the `Guid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I convert it? Does it just crop the first 24 symbols of hex
>   representation of the Guid?

Not exactly. It's actually Guid bytes (as returned by `MongoDB.Bson.GuidConverter.ToBytes(guid, GuidRepresentation.CSharpLegacy)`) converted to Base64 string. Here is C# code that does such conversion:

```
var str = Convert.ToBase64String(MongoDB.Bson.GuidConverter.ToBytes(guid, GuidRepresentation.CSharpLegacy));
```

For example, for Guid `{a6f262e1-2b58-4c90-89f2-f12c4fad19b1}` it will result to `4WLyplgrkEyJ8vEsT60ZsQ==`.

Comment: Turns out that Mongo uses different algorythms for different language versions or mongo versions or whatever that is. There is this class  `Mongo.Bson.GuidConverter` that can be used to fetch the byte array of the `Guid` that can be later passed as a param to the `Convert.ToBase64String`, but it works differently for each value of the `GuidRepresentation` enum. In my case, the correct one was `GuidRepresentation.CSharpLegacy`.

Comment: Thank you for this correction. Sure, it's better to use existing converter than reinvent the wheels :)